# Project structure for desktop applications using SQLAlchemy and wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, sqlalchemy, desktop, project-structure

I want to create a desktop application using SQLAlchemy and wxPython, but I'd like to structure the project in a way similar to django projects, using django app-like packages (related models, views and tests in the same package) and settings and main module in the root directory.

I'd like to know if that is a good structure and how to do that minimizing coupling between packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly do it that way. I recently started a project with another fellow to demonstrate one way to do just this sort of thing. You're welcome to take a look at how we separate all this stuff out here: https://github.com/driscollis/MediaLocker

It's gotten a little abstract, but I think you can still use it as  a model anyway. Hope that helps!

Comment: Your example is great! Though, one thing that I'd thought was of using settings (like APPS in Django) and don't referencing the project directly in app packages, increasing the packages' plug'n play-ness.

Comment: We've refactored it quite a bit. Feel free to mention that as a possible bug on Bitbucket if you like. I'm not sure if we can comply completely with MVC, but we can get pretty close.

Comment: I've adopted that structure, with a few adaptations. It would be simple adapt to a structure similar to django, but I think your project's structure is more simple and it serves for my purposes :-)

Comment: I’m very curious to see this structure. Is the source code still available? The link is now broken. I’m mostly wondering how you manage the db session in the app and when you commit. Thanks!

Comment: @mihow - I moved this to GitHub here: https://github.com/driscollis/MediaLocker